# How can I extend the background color of the left nav to be the same height as the main content area?

Tags: html, css

How can I extend the background color of the left nav to be the same height as the main content area? The background would need to increase too if a slidetoggle is used. Please see the JSfiddle for markup example:http://jsfiddle.net/8WJRQ/

I want the styling for #nav to extend the same height as .main-content (with out any changes to the HTML structure, b/c i am using a 12 column template.)

*I should mention that the numbered classes (.two and .ten) can't be changed because they are part of a global template.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="two columns">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul><li>Home</li><li>News</li><li>About </li></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ten columns">
        <div class="main-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <a href="#" onclick="$('.foo').slideToggle()">Toggle Text</a>
            <p class="foo">Lorem ipsum<br>
            hello<br>
            world</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can the content be wrapped in a container, or is the HTML automatically generated

Comment: @Cody Guldner: Yes, any markup that is a child of .ten or .two can be changed.

Comment: @CodyGuldner: Can you elaborate as if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `table`, `table-cell` and `table-row` css properties.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

and put background into `.two .columns`

http://jsfiddle.net/G6sdD/

**update**

ok here is a js version. i didn't really put much thought into it. so there might be a better way of doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/vGNXb/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var height = $('.ten.columns').height();
$('.two.columns').height(height);
});
function extend(){
    $('.foo').slideToggle(function(){
         var height = $('.ten.columns').height();
         $('.two.columns').height(height);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is good, but I know IE7 doesn't support table-cell. Is there a way to accomplish this on the #nav ID. I should mention that the CSS for the numbered classes (.two and .ten) shouldn't really change since it is part of the global 12 column template. Do you think this might only be achievable through JS?

Comment: @C3P-Bro yeah probably you can do it with JS. but imho this is a better solution. IE7 is pretty outdated. it's used by like 1 percent. i wouldnt worry about IE7.

Comment: @C3P-Bro ok I added a js version.